# How to build an npm package with a whole Vue.js application?

Tags: vue.js, npm

Is it possible to build a whole Vue.js application into an npm package? I only see documentation about packaging a component, but not a whole application.

I would like to import a vuejs app as a web component into another application

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by packaging a complete app? Are you trying to build a component library or something intended to be imported into another application? If so, how would it be used?

Comment: Hello, yes I want to import this app into another as a web component

Comment: I am ignorant in the web component arena, so I could not collaborate there.  However, if you haven't comitted to web components and are willing to test other things, I would suggest `single-spa` or similar micro-frontend frameworks.

Comment: I am also not 100% sure on this so I'll just recommend looking at `vue-web-component-wrapper` on npm, it's by the Vue team and should just be a matter of following the instructions, providing it your entry vue app component and export that as your npm package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches, I found out a solution.

### Build the application as a web component

1. Add `vue3-webcomponent-wrapper` dependency on the project
2. Create a `main.ce.ts` which creates the web component:

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import wrapper from "vue3-webcomponent-wrapper";
import App from './App.vue';

const CustomElement = wrapper(App, createApp, h);
window.customElements.define("my-component", CustomElement);
```

3. Edit `vite.config.ts` to add/edit with the following:

```json
plugins: [vue({
    template: {
      compilerOptions: {
        isCustomElement: (tag: string) => tag.includes('my-component')
      }
    }
})],
build: {
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    lib: {
      entry: './src/main.ce.ts',
      name: 'my-component',
      fileName: 'my-component'
    }
},
define: { 'process.env': process.env }
```

4. Add a script in `package.json`: `"build-ce": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build"`

### Publish on npm

1. Edit `package.json` to add the following:

```json
"files": [
  "dist"
],
"main": "./dist/my-component.umd.cjs",
"module": "./dist/my-component.js",
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "import": "./dist/my-component.js",
    "require": "./dist/my-component.umd.cjs"
  }
}
```

2. Run `npm run build-ce` and verify output
3. Run `npm publish`

### Use the web component into another application

1. Add the package to the project dependencies
2. Import the `my-component.js` script into the app. For instance, with an angular app, we should edit `angular.json`:

```json
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/vuejs-example-npm-package/dist/vuejs-example.js"
]
```

3. Use the component with the tag `my-component`. We can pass params to the component and listen for changes.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, my understanding is that you want to package some components so that they can be used inside your other Vue.js application. If that is the case, you would develop a plugin or module that hooks into the Vue.js App instance.

This is what some packages like [`v-safe-url`](https://github.com/dxphilo/v-safe-url) and [`vue-use`](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse) do under the hood, among other Vue plugins. These plugins provide additional functionality or components that can be imported and used in Vue.js applications.

To get you started consider checking out this links:

- [Plugins](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins#plugins)
- [Writing a Plugin](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins#writing-a-plugin)